# How to find the leaf of a binary tree?

Tags: c++, pointers, search, recursion, binary-tree

I am writing a binary tree with a search function. The function is supposed to take an argument x which denotes the value to be searched and once it is found, determine if it is a leaf or not. If the value is not found, the search functions returns false.

Here is what I have which gives me a seg fault and has been just giving me false returns for every value from 1 to 100. The binary tree is initalized with 100 values.

```
bool search(Node<T>* &currentNode, const T& x) const
{
    //~ cout << "CURRENT NODE DATA: " << currentNode->data << "   :   ";


    /*  FUNCTION: Searches for variable that is passed in X and checks if this value is a leaf or not */

    //Left Subtree Search
    if (x < currentNode->data)
    {

    if ((leaf(currentNode)) == true)
        { 
          return true;
        }
    else 
    {
    search(currentNode->left, x);   

    }

    }


//Right Subtree Search
else if (x >= currentNode->data)
{

    //If node in right subtree is a node check 
    if ((leaf(currentNode)) == true)
    {
        return true;
    }   

    else 
    {
    search(currentNode->right, x);
    }

}




 //Return false if the node is not a leaf
 return false;

}  //END OF SEARCH FUNCTION



void remove(Node<T>* &currentNode, const T& x)
{

}

bool leaf(Node<T>* currentNode) const 
{
    if (currentNode != nullptr)
    {
    return ((currentNode->left == nullptr && currentNode->right == nullptr) ? true : false);        
    }
    else 
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: On what line do you get a seg fault? you also assume the binary tree is sorted (ie, each node is bigger than left, smaller or equal to right). Does your function receive a sorted binary tree?

Comment: I insert the elements in a descending order by value.

Comment: I meant [self balancing tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree). Either way, if x is on a node that is not a leaf, the function will never find it, since it can only return true for a leaf node. This is not a complete answer, but you should have some part of the function that reads `if(x==currentNode->data) return true;` (since you are searching for value x.) You should probably seperate fixing the seg fault and asking for the algorithm instead of just dumping the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additionally, the `leaf` function returns true when `currentNode` is `nullptr`, assuming the check for `nullptr` in `search` is resolved.  Is this the behavior you want for a pointer pointing to a non-existent leaf?

Comment: The leaf function also returns true if both left and right child are null pointers. I used the tenary operator to return true or false. Perhaps something is wrong with the expression and it never returns true?

Comment: @Revoo The way I see it is that there should be two base cases in the `search` function, otherwise there will be problems.  Both of them have already been mentioned between the comment and answer posts.  After updating the code, testing it, and subsequently updating the question details, then there might be more for the rest of us to review and help with.

Answer (score 0):

In your search function, you recourse on the child nodes without seeing if they're nullptr first... Then you try to de reference the data element still without checking for null.